# Django - How to dynamically restrict category of blog post?

Tags: python, django, foreign-keys

I'm working on a blog project. I want to set primary and secondary categories for the posts. For example,

primary category: Music, Movie, Computer
and secondary categories for each primary category like: 
Music - Dance, Rock, Country /
Movie - Script, Teaser, Review /
Computer - Hardware, Software /

And when I create a new post I want to restrict secondary category choices according to the primary category I chose. 
(to be precise, in the post creation form, 
first, I want both primary and secondary categories to be shown in dropdown menus, and 
second, after I choose a primary category I want only the secondary category choices which belong to the primary category I chose to be shown in the dropdown menu for secondary category.)

Currently my models.py:

```
class PrimaryCategory(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField('Primary Category', max_length=50)

class SecondaryCategory(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField('Secondary Category', max_length=50)
    primary = models.ForeignKey(PrimaryCategory,on_delete=models.CASCADE)

class Post(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=256)
    content = models.TextField()
    create_date = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    author = models.ForeignKey(User, null=True, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    primary_category = models.ForeignKey(PrimaryCategory, on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True)
    secondary_category = models.ForeignKey(SecondaryCategory, on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True)
```

and I searched and I can maybe use ForeignKey.limit_choices_to in my ModelForms, but I'm stuck here. Could anybody kindly help writing my forms.py?

currently I only have forms.py like:

```
from django import forms
from myblog.models import Post,PrimaryCategory,SecondaryCategory

class PostForm(forms.ModelForm):

    secondary_category = models.ForeignKey(
        PrimaryCategory,
        on_delete=models.CASCADE,
        limit_choices_to= ??? ,
    )

    class Meta:
        model=Post
```

to summerize:

1. how to show category choices in dropdown menu instead of free text input?
2. how to dynamically restrict secondary category choices according to primary category choice in the form?

(Added) 3. I have no working knowledge of javascript, so I want to do it without JS if possible..If it is not possible to change choices dynamically, then is it at least possible to make the form to give me an error message if secondary category choice I made is not under chosen primary cagetory? I think I'll work on it but any advice would be of great help.

I would appreciate any help. Thank you.

Comment: The fact that the field is a ForeignKey will take care of limiting the choices.

Comment: You need to use JQuery or simillar JS library to add restriction dynamically.

Comment: #Red Cricket But with the code above I can choose primary and secondary categories independently. Like: primary category : Computer / secondary category: Dance and it can be just saved. I want the form not to allow the post to be saved if secondary category does not belong to the primary category I chose. (actually I want the secondary category choices which are not under the primary category not to be shown so that it is impossible to select them)

Comment: # ruddra Thank you, maybe using jQuery is a bit too much for my current level of learning..then any idea how the form can at least give me an error message and prevent from saving the post if I make wrong 2ndary category choices? I think it should be possible without any JS because the relationship is already defined in the model..

Answer (score 0):

I googled and found exactly what I wanted here:

https://simpleisbetterthancomplex.com/tutorial/2018/01/29/how-to-implement-dependent-or-chained-dropdown-list-with-django.html

It needs jQuery and I actually didn't fully understand what's happening in the jQuery part of the solution, but otherwise everything's clear and it works perfect!